# Explain why, with $h>0$, the two limits, $\lim_{h\to 0} Pr(b-h<X\leq b)$ and $\lim_{h\to 0} F_{X}(b-h)$ exist.

Tags: probability-theory

I'm not sure if I am even proving it correctly. Can you guys take a look at my work below?

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be the space of a random variable $X$. Consider $A\subset \mathscr{A}$ where $A=\{X:b-h<X\leq b\}$, for $h>0$.

Consider
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} Pr(b-h<X\leq b)
$$
By definition,
$$
Pr(b-h<X\leq b)=
Pr(X\in A)=
\mathbb{P}_{X}(A)
$$
Thus we need to find $\lim_{h\to 0}\mathbb{P}_{X}(A)$ which boils down to finding

$$
\lim_{h\to 0} A=\lim_{h\to 0} \{x:b-h<x\leq b\}=\{x:b<x\leq b\}=\{x:x=b\}
$$
And so
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\mathbb{P}_{X}(A) = Pr(X=b)
$$
Thus $\lim_{h\to 0} Pr(b-h<X\leq b)$ exists.

Also
$$
Pr(b-h<X\leq b) = F_{X}(b) - F_{X}(b-h)
$$
This is as far as I got before my brain became numb. Am I even doing this right?

Comment: It is not at all valid. Define $\lim_{h \to 0} A$. How do you know that if sets converge then  their probabilites converge?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If I start with sets $A_{0}, A_{1}, A_{2},\ldots$ where $A_{h}\subset A_{h+1}$ and let $A_{h}=\{x:b-h<x\leq b\}$, I can define $\lim_{h\to 0}A_{h}$ as the intersection $A_{0}\cap A_{1}\cap A_{2}\cap\cdots$. Is this a valid definition? For your second question, I know a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on set $A_{h}$ is a probability set function $\mathbb{P}(A_{h})$ for $A_{h}\subset \mathscr{A}$ where $\mathscr{A}$ is the space of $X$. I would want $\lim_{h\to 0}A_{h} \in \mathscr{A}$, and if so, then wouldn't $\lim_{h\to 0}\mathbb{P}(A_{h})=\mathbb{P}(\lim_{h\to 0}A_{h})$?